# How to remove italic lettering from the proof, definition and remark environments?

Tags: text

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}
Theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{rem}
Remark.
\end{rem}
\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}
Proposition.
\end{prop}
\begin{cor}
Corollary.
\end{cor}
\begin{defn}
Definition.
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
Theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

which provides the following:

[image]

How do I remove `\textit` from the content of the proof (in my example that is: some proof here), definition and remark? I have tried to change the `\newtheorem` command but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid a statement such as "I have tried to change the `\newtheorem` command but it didn't work" isn't actionable. It would be very helpful if you provided some information about *what* you tried in terms of modifying `\newtheorem`. Anyway, please see the answer I posted for a solution which (a) modifes the `\newtheorem` command and (b) works. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't have much experience with LaTeX so I cannot fix some things by myself.

Answer (score 4):

Just load `amsthm` and use `\theoremstyle{definition}` for those environments in which you don't want italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}
Theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{rem}
Remark.
\end{rem}
\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}
Proposition.
\end{prop}
\begin{cor}
Corollary.
\end{cor}
\begin{defn}
Definition.
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
Theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

(I modified my answer after realizing that the OP desires to change the body font of just a few, but not all, theorem-like environments.)

I suggest you load the [ntheorem](https://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package and issue the instruction `\theorembodyfont{\upshape}` right before `\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}`. That way, only the final three `\newtheorem` declarations will be affected by the font change.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically

\usepackage{ntheorem} % for '\theorembodyfont' macro

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{thm}   Theorem. \end{thm}
\begin{rem}   Remark.  \end{rem}
\begin{lem}   Lemma.   \end{lem}
\begin{prop}  Proposition. \end{prop}
\begin{cor}   Corollary.   \end{cor}
\begin{defn}  Definition.  \end{defn}
\begin{thm}   Theorem. \end{thm}
\begin{proof} Proof.   \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make \begin{proof} Proof.   \end{proof} without proof numbering (Proof 1, Proof 2, ...)?

Comment: @Alezigl - Sure. Just change `\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}` to `\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alezigl - Just out of idle curiosity: I thought that the only thing that you wanted to change about the appearance of the `defn`, `rem`, and `proof` environments was the font shape, from italic to upright; that's why I suggested using the `ntheorem` package. I've noticed that you accepted the other answer, which adds periods (aka "full stops") after the number of the theorem-like environments. (This happens because the other answer employs the `amsthm` package.) Question, not at all meant to pressure you: Was my assumption that you wouldn't want these extra periods simply unwarranted?

Comment: No, not at all. Both answers are very useful. I thought, namely, that I accepted both, but now I realized that this is not possible, so I voted up for both. Some academic journals require the form of: `Theorem 1.1`, and some require the form of:`Theorem 1.1.`, so both answers work for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Alezigl - Many thanks for you follow-up.